# Bash: Quickly find diff of two files of second column only if the first column is the same

Tags: bash, awk, diff

I have two large files around 7GB each. I would like to find the difference of the second file only if the number of the first column is the same for the two files. The two files are sorted but can have different number of lines.

The first file looks like this: (1.txt)

```
5 5
6 6
7 7 
8 8
9 9
```

The second file looks like this: (2.txt):

```
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 4 
8 4
9 9
```

*The output should look like this:*

```
7 4
8 4
```

Right now I have this one-liner, but I am not sure if it can go faster:

`mawk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} ($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$2' 1.txt 2.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the files are sorted on the joined key, the easiest (and fastest) will be

```
$ join file1 file2 | awk '$2!=$3{print $1,$3}'

7 4
8 4
```

Comment: Yes, that is much faster and beautiful. Thank you. I didn't expect from join to be that much faster. I guess that it can even gain some seconds by using mawk.